# How to send mail/alert when message moved to Dead Letter Queue (ASB DLQ)?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, dead-letter

I am trying to send a mail alert when message passed to Azure Service Bus Dead Letter Queue. I did not find any proper solution to send mail alert.
Can we process this in which side azure or .net core? if so can anyone help with the process

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Azure Monitor for this. The ASB emits a metric "Count of dead-lettered messages in a Queue/Topic" ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-metrics-azure-monitor#message-metrics)) which you can create an alert on.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-overview#overview) is an overview on how to set up the alert.

Step 1, create alert

[image]

Step 2, select signal

[image]

Next steps: configure thresholds and setup an action group to send an email.

Comment: seems like the alert can only be set at the queue or topic level... no option to set it for a subscription (which makes more sense than a topic)